# how to extract list of ids from changing array field in java script?

Tags: javascript, postman

I am writing tests in postman and I would like to extract the list of Ids inside variants object matching condition where `stock.available ==true` and `quantity > 3`. However my issues lies that number inside `variants` object is random value which is 194922428018, 194922428025 and 194922428032. Final output should results only `194922428025` and `194922428032` which are the items with stock. Thanks in Advance.

```
[{
    "appIdentifier": "53443434w-813f-4b59-b58a-deaf76847845",
    "categoryIds": null,
    "id": "205148",
    "variants": {
        "194922428018": {
            "id": "194922428018",
            "filterAttributes": null,
            "meta": {
                    "ean": "609332822610"
                },
            "stock": {
                "available": false,
                "lowOnStock": true,
                "leadTime": null,
                "quantity": 0
            },
            "categoryIds": null
        },
        "194922428025": {
            "id": "194922428025",
            "filterAttributes": null,
            "stock": {
                "available": true,
                "lowOnStock": true,
                "leadTime": null,
                "quantity": 9
            },
            "categoryIds": null
        },
        "194922428032": {
            "id": "194922428032",
            "filterAttributes": null,
            "stock": {
                "available": true,
                "lowOnStock": false,
                "leadTime": null,
                "quantity": 33
            },
            "categoryIds": null
        }
}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: iterate thought your "variant" object and check forEach object inside, if object.stock.available === true && object.stock.quantity > 3

Comment: You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or a simple [`for .. in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

Comment: @0stone0 but as `variants` is an object and not an array that doesn't seem to work here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this would work for you

```
const testArray = [{
    "appIdentifier": "53443434w-813f-4b59-b58a-deaf76847845",
    "categoryIds": null,
    "id": "205148",
    "variants": {
        "194922428018": {
            "id": "194922428018",
            "filterAttributes": null,
            "stock": {
                "available": false,
                "lowOnStock": true,
                "leadTime": null,
                "quantity": 0
            },
            "categoryIds": null
        },
        "194922428025": {
            "id": "194922428025",
            "filterAttributes": null,
            "stock": {
                "available": true,
                "lowOnStock": true,
                "leadTime": null,
                "quantity": 9
            },
            "categoryIds": null
        },
        "194922428032": {
            "id": "194922428032",
            "filterAttributes": null,
            "stock": {
                "available": true,
                "lowOnStock": false,
                "leadTime": null,
                "quantity": 33
            },
            "categoryIds": null
        }
}}
]

const ids = Object.entries(testArray[0]['variants']).reduce((acc, [key, value])=>{
    if(value.stock.available && value.stock.quantity > 3) acc.push(key)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(ids) // ["194922428025", "194922428032"]
```

Comment: Above works perfectly for above use case but what needs to be done if I want to get `meta.ean` value as well? I have updated the original JSON to add meta object

Comment: you can read like this ,`variants['194922428032']['meta']['ean']` 
what is the required output?

Comment: the required output is to extract ean value --> `609332822610`

Comment: I don't think I can use `variants['194922428032']['meta']['ean']` because `194922428032` this is dynamic and varies on each request. @nithin-pb

Comment: not sure this is the required solution `const eans = ids.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
 const item = testArray[0].variants[curr]
  if(item?.meta?.ean) acc.push(item.meta.ean)
  return acc
}, [])`

this is an extension to the original answer